# itemize block color in a0poster

Tags: pdftex, a0poster

I am creating a a0 size poster in `a0poster` class.
Is it possible to change the color of itemize block?
I can change the textcolor line by line, but not the bullets:

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
%what I can do
\begin{itemize}
  \item \textcolor{green}{pros is green color}
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \textcolor{red}{cons in rec dolor}
\end{itemize}

%what I want
\color{green}{
\begin{itemize}
  \item whole block with bullets will be green
  \item including all the itemes inside this block
\end{itemize}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define specialised lists with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{prositemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[prositemize]{label=\textbullet, before=\color{DarkSeaGreen3}\sffamily}
\newlist{consitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[consitemize]{label=\textbullet, before=\color{IndianRed2}\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\begin{prositemize}
  \item pros is green color
\end{prositemize}
\begin{consitemize}
  \item icons in red color
\end{consitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]